# How to simulate authenticated users in functional tests in Silex php framework

Tags: functional-testing, silex

I am trying to functional test a page protected by authentication form.

My code is based on this link: http://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/simulating_authentication.html

But it still does not work for me.

Here is thye error message that I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client::getContainer()
```

Here is my code:

```
class ClientTest extends WebTestCase {

    public function createApplication()
    {
        return require __DIR__.'/../app.php';
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function index_when_no_clients()
    {
        $this->client = $this->createClient();
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/');

        $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isOk());
        $this->assertCount(1, $crawler->filter('h1:contains("Clients")'));
        $this->assertCount(1, $crawler->filter('span[class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"]'));
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function add_get_route_is_valid()
    {
        $client = $this->createClient();
        $session = $client->getContainer()->get('session');

        // the firewall context (defaults to the firewall name)
        $firewall = 'secured_area';

        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken('admin', null, $firewall, array('ROLE_ADMIN'));
        $session->set('_security_'.$firewall, serialize($token));
        $session->save();

        $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
        $client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/add'); 

        $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isOk());
    }   
}
```

Here is how I am setting authentication in my index.php:

```
$app->register(new \Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider(), [
    'session.test' => 'test' === $app['env'],
]);
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'admin' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/add',
            'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/add/login_check'),
            'users' => $app->share(function() use ($app) {
                $config = Configuration::getInstance();
                $pdoQueries = new PdoQueries(PdoConnection::getInstance($config));
                return new UserProvider($pdoQueries);
            }),
        ),
    )
));

$app->get('/login', function(Request $request) use ($app, $arrConfig) {
    return $app['twig']->render('auth/form.twig', array(
            'error'         => $app['security.last_error']($request),
            'last_username' => $app['session']->get('_security.last_username'),
            'title'         => 'Login',
            'assetsUrl'             => $arrConfig['assets_url']
    ));
});
```

And here is the content of the app.php called in createApplication:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ ."/../www/index.php";
unset($app['exception_handler']);
return $app;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem and the solution.

The problem was the getContainer statement. Dependency injection is called in a different way in silex. just calling

```
$app['session']
```

directly solved the problem.

Here is the full script with the symfony classes to import as well.

```
<?php 
use Silex\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Cookie;

class ClientTest extends WebTestCase {

    public function createApplication()
    {
        return require __DIR__.'/../app.php';
    }

    private function logIn($client)
    {
        $session = $this->app['session'];
        $firewall = 'admin';
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken('admin', null, $firewall, array('ROLE_ADMIN'));
        $session->set('_security_'.$firewall, serialize($token));
        $session->save();
        $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
        $client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);

        return $client;
    }   

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function index_when_no_clients()
    {
        $this->client = $this->createClient();
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/');

        $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isOk());
        $this->assertCount(1, $crawler->filter('h1:contains("Clients")'));
        $this->assertCount(1, $crawler->filter('span[class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"]'));
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function add_get_route_is_valid()
    {
        $client = $this->createClient();
        $client = $this->logIn($client);
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/add'); 

        $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isOk());
    }   

}
```

Hope that will help other people.